# Obout.Interface.OboutTextBox' is null or not an object error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, grid, obout

When I use my below JS FIDDLE, I get error as

> Obout.Interface.OboutTextBox' is null or not an object in IE.

I don't know what is the issue here

I get error at line no 308 which is

```
Obout.Interface.OboutTextBox.prototype.applyCrossBrowserFixes = function (){}
```

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/de2nh862)

Please suggest what is wrong

Comment: you can't reproduce the issue in jsfiddle. so reproduce the issue  at-least in a live site and give the link. If you can't reproduce , then i am sorry i can't help.

Comment: @JSantosh: we are working on localhost, how would i be able to make it live ?

Comment: @JSantosh: can you tell me what exactly do you want. so i can give or mail you the respective files

Comment: that was resolved by putting the script in the head tag. Now i m facing issue of `Line: 308 Error: 'Obout.Interface.OboutTextBox' is null or not an object` with this jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/de2nh862/

Comment: ohk, then ask new question by tagging `oboutgrid` which helps people to find the question easily. i didn't work with `oboutgrid`.

Comment: can i tag here. because this is related to the same js file issue

Comment: try it . and update question title

Comment: @JSantosh: updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91584/discussion-between-nadeem-and-j-santosh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure those function is not wrapped around by document ready. Place it only inside `<script></script>` :

**Not like this :**

```
<script>
// or $(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
  function navigateThroughCells(sender, key, forced) { .... }
});
</script>
```

**But like this :**

```
<script>
  function navigateThroughCells(sender, key, forced) { .... }
</script>
```

Comment: i have called that function in **a separate JS file**

Comment: @nadeem load the js file in head tag and try

Comment: @nadeem : Where you put that?

Comment: @JSantosh: loaded the file in head tag, but still getting the same error

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: I tried adding that in head tag. have a look http://jsfiddle.net/g5tbemoy/

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: Resolved that issue, but now it is giving me error as `oboutGrid is not defined` at line no 4 of JS function

Comment: Alright, if you talking about code in jsfiddle, `oboutGrid` does't have class function. Which all prototype created without references. Same goes to `Obout`. Did you created already those function?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: So what should I do in to make it work properly ?

Comment: getting error as `Line: 308
Error: 'Obout.Interface.OboutTextBox' is null or not an object`

Comment: @nadeem reproduce the issue in fiddle , that's the last option i got to help you .

Comment: Seems like your code lack of relevant function. Most of them rely on other function to run with. Where you got this snippet?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: I downloaded it from obout gridview, from here https://www.obout.com/grid/commands/aspnet_commands_excel_style_full.aspx

Comment: @JSantosh: can you help me with this issue, also i have added one js fiddle in the comment. One more thing i am getting this error in `IE`

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: any suggestions on this?? please sir as i am clueless what to do now

Comment: Can't help mate since i do not have completed code and can't to play with `asp.net` things.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali: atleast can we try to resolve this issue. See what I want is. if i click on any cell and edit it, it should allow me to do so. For this if you have any other option. let me know

Comment: With normal html markup and some js code should fine. If done editing, what to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91572/discussion-between-nadeem-and-norlihazmey-ghazali).